# GUI time is different than command line time

Tags: locale

I have kind of an odd problem. The time in my Unity bar is right, but the time in bash is 2 hours ahead.

```
$ date
Wed Jun 20 15:31:55 CDT 2012
```

Unity bar:

```
Wed Jun 20 13:31:55
```

Here are my etc configs:

```
$ cat /etc/timezone
America/Los_Angeles
```

locale:

```
$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Finally, I tried `$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata` and setting it to "Los_Angeles".

Has anyone seen anything like this?

**EDIT**

So I installed Ubuntu on another computer and after I installed updates using dist-upgrate, it was 2 hours ahead again... On a completely new computer. Here is the output from apt: http://pastebin.com/jMffJNs4

Comment: Is your BIOS clock set to UTC or local time? If it's UTC, `/etc/default/rcS` should have a line `UTC=yes`, otherwise `UTC=no`.

Comment: @elmicha My bios is set to UTC and UTC=yes is set in /etc/default/rcS and it's still using the CDT timezone in bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was all my fault.

It was a local TZ var on the profile level being sourced that was hard to find.